# How to embed c-span videos in my web page

Tags: java, javascript, html

How can I embed c-span videos in my web page. Does a c-span API for Java, or JavaScript exist. I don't want to put the entire videos web page in an iframe. I just want the video itself embedded in my web page, if it is embedded as an iframe then so be it. I  want an API that can query for links and images, and embed videos. Thank you!

I apologize if I am not being very clear, but sometimes I speak better Java than I do English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to the video and click on Share... There you can see "embed code" Click on copy embed code and paste it into your website.

Comment: This is a good answer, but I'm not going to check it as solved just yet. I really want an API to do things automatically. I can't believe I missed that on the videos. Thank you!

Comment: What links and images do you want to query?

Comment: All links and images to videos.